How to update yajra datatable without refreshing page in laravel 10
I am using Yajra Laravel DataTable
I want to update the table on an AJAX response after deleting a record from the table. Using this we can manage all the things from the data table file instead of initializing the table from java script.

I have researched various solutions, and I noticed that most people initialize DataTables using the following method:
$('.data-table').DataTable({});
However, I prefer not to use this method because all configurations are managed within a separate DataTable file. Therefore,  I would like to understand how to update the table correctly.
As I am new to Laravel, I would appreciate guidance on the proper way to achieve this.
